# Action bar tab fragments on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Is there a way to completely remove fragments that are associated with action bar tab? My application has 2 tabs in portrait view. When in landscap view I load a completely different fragment view. when I go from portrait view to to land, the fragment from the last tab that was selected overlays the fragment in landscap.

Is there a way to ensure that tab fragments from portrait view never get recreated in when orientation changes?

EDIT: I am using dynamic fragments. All of the fragments get added to the same framlayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by locating fragment by tag when activity is recreated by calling parents fragment manager:

```
 Fragment frag = super.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
if (frag != null)
fragTransaction.remove(frag);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change orientation you recreate the activity and thereby all your fragments. It should be quite trivial for you to handle this case based on the orientation in your onCreate method of your main Activity.

To get orientation use:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Comment: Regardless of the orientation the OS will recreate the last fragment. So if you go from portrait mode to land the fragment in portrait will get recreated again when activity starts on land mode.

Comment: @user1935235 that depend on if you pass the savedInstanceState and how you created the fragment.

Comment: Thats a very generic statement. Can you explain your point of view  further?